# Codeforces Round #255 "Modifying matrix" solution(Div-1 B)?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I was trying to solve the "**DZY Loves Modification**" problem from Round #255 of CodeForces.

> Problem link: 
>   http://codeforces.com/contest/446/problem/B.

I am getting wrong answers for the system test cases.

My approach is as follows:

1. Construct two **max-heaps** - one heap for storing the row totals and
   one for the column totals
2. Store two variables - **rowReductionValue** and **colReductionValue** -
   these variables store the value that **should be subtracted** before
   **using** a **row** or **column's total** sum.
3. For each iteration, choose the entry with maximum value from the
   rowSum and colSum heaps
4. If a row is chosen, the row's total is added to the result and then
   the row total is reduced by P * (number_of_columns)
5. After this, each column's value reduces by P. So, this P is
   **added** to colReductionValue.
6. An analogous approach is used if a column is chosen.

This approach results in wrong answers.

I am sorry if I was not clear in explaining my approach, I wanted it to be as concise as possible.

Any light on the right approach or the flaw with this approach is much appreciated.

The code is below:

```
long long getMaxResult(int rows, int cols, int reductionValue, int K)
{
    vector<long long> rowSums, colSums;
    long long rowReductionValue = 0, colReductionValue = 0, result = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        long long sum = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            sum += a[row][col];
        }
        rowSums.push_back(sum);
    }

    for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
    {
        long long sum = 0;
        for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        {
            sum += a[row][col];
        }
        colSums.push_back(sum);
    }

    make_heap(rowSums.begin(), rowSums.end());
    make_heap(colSums.begin(), colSums.end());

    for(int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
    {
        pop_heap(rowSums.begin(), rowSums.end());
        long long rowMax = rowSums.back();
        rowSums.pop_back();

        pop_heap(colSums.begin(), colSums.end());
        long long colMax = colSums.back();
        colSums.pop_back();

        if(rowMax - rowReductionValue >= colMax - colReductionValue)
        {
            result += rowMax - rowReductionValue;
            rowMax -= reductionValue * cols;
            colReductionValue += reductionValue;
        }
        else
        {
            result += colMax - colReductionValue;
            colMax -= reductionValue * rows;
            rowReductionValue += reductionValue;
        }

        rowSums.push_back(rowMax);
        push_heap(rowSums.begin(), rowSums.end());

        colSums.push_back(colMax);
        push_heap(colSums.begin(), colSums.end());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk you through the Greedy-Brute Force concept that I used to approach this problem:

If *p = 0*, apparently the best choice is choosing the row or column which can give greatest pleasure value each time.

Let's ignore *p* first, then we can get a greatest number *ans* using previous statement. Now if we choose rows for *i* times, choose column for *k-i* times, *ans* should be *ans<sub>i</sub> - ((k-i) X i X p)*.

So we could enumerate i from 0 to k and calculate *ans<sub>i</sub> - ((k-i) X i X p)* each time, max{*ans<sub>i</sub> - ((k-i) X i X p)*} is the maximum possible pleasure value DZY could get.

Let *a<sub>i</sub>* be the maximum pleasure value we can get after choosing *i* rows and *b<sub>i</sub>* be the maximum pleasure value we can get after choosing *i* columns. Then *ans<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i</sub>+b<sub>k-i</sub>*. We can use two priority queues to calculate *a<sub>i</sub>* and *b<sub>i</sub>* quickly.

Good luck!